# Is it correct to say "penetrable to reasons"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I heard this phrase before: "He is impenetrable to reasons.". It seems to me it means he is NOT a logical or sensible person.

However, can I say "He is penetrable to reasons.", to mean that he is a logical and sensible person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "impenetrable to reason". Reason here is a non-count noun meaning "What is right, practical, or possible; common sense." If someone is impenetrable to reason then they cannot be influenced by arguments based on common sense or logic.

"Penetrable to reason" is not a common expression. To convey the opposite meaning, I would rather say "he is susceptible to reason".

Comment: I see, "reason" should be a non-count noun here.If it is right to say "impenetrable to reason", can I also say "penetrable to reason" to mean the opposite?